# Sticky Footer not working for some reason

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I have tried to get sticky footer working on the site below but for some reason the veritcal scroll bar appears:

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com/

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please include all relevant code within your question.  Otherwise it will be useless to future readers.

Comment: Not sure adding code is relevant to be honest, without pasting in the whole CSS and HTML, you did raise a good point though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `border-top`.
Adding this to the `body` CSS should fix it in most modern browsers:

```
body{
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your vertical scroll-bar is being caused by this...

```
body {
    border-top: 5px solid #293649;
}
```

and...

```
html, body, #container  {
    height: 100%;
}
```

As per the [W3C Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), the 5 pixel border on your `body` is being **added** to the `height` of the `body` which is already at `100%`.  This effectively makes your `body` element's height `100%` plus 5 pixels at all times, hence the scroll-bar.

To solve it, try moving the border to a different element.  I'll be able to post a more exact solution if your question can be condensed to just the minimum amount of code required to reproduce.   As it stands, there's just more code than I'm willing to dig through.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the footer to stick you just need the following

```
#footer {
   position: fixed
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 100; /** some of the content has a z-index higher than 0 so I chose 100 randomly **/
}
```

Comment: This is a different type of sticky footer.  He only wants the footer to stick when there is not enough content to fill the space, otherwise the content has to push the footer down.